# Delete and replace folder within %username% structure

Tags: windows-server-2008, user-profiles

I'm trying to clean up our Office Templates directory as it's gotten a bit overcrowded and needs a bit of a trim. I've initially written a batch file to copy the Templates directory and its contents over from the `Default User.V2` on the DC each time a user logs in but this doesn't remove the folder and its contents ready for a fresh copy. I also don't want the deletion to happen all the time, as users will create their own templates in the future.

Obviously we have a few users profile folders that need their Templates folder removed and replaced with this new Template folder and I'm wondering what the best way to go about it *en masse*.

This is the UNC: `\\server\profiles$\firstname.lastname.V2\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates` with firstname.lastname.V2 being the stickler.

Is batch file / VBS the best way here?

Answer (score 0):

You could make it so that at logout a backup script occurs. So, login, delete local template folder, copy from DC. Logout, copy template folder back to DC.

This should preserve changes they make.